# Play application configurations not loading?

Tags: java, playframework

Configurations for my Play module are not loading.

The project structure for my build and config files looks like:

```
/project/modules/my_module/build.sbt
/project/modules/conf/my_conf.conf
```

I run the project with:

```
cd /project/modules/my_module
sbt "run -Dconfig.resource=conf/my_conf.conf"
```

When I read the setting, it is null:

```
String mySetting = Play.application().configuration().getString("my_setting")
```

From debugging the application, it appears none of my settings are loaded into `Play.application.configuration()`.

I used `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to verify that the working driectory is `/project/modules/my_module/` so `conf/my_conf.conf` should be the right path. Any suggestions how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Are you behind any proxy?try  sbt run "-Dconfig.resource=conf/my_conf.conf"

Comment: You should run the app like sbt run "-Dconfig.resource=conf/my_conf.conf"

Comment: I don't think I'm behind a proxy, how would I know if I am? when I run that command, I get a configuration error when I open localhost:9000 in a browser (I don't get the configuration error when I run the sbt command in my post): `Configuration error: pplication: application.conf: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.conf, application.json: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.json, application.properties: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.properties`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have default config file `application.conf` in your classpath, try to rename `my_conf.conf` to `application.conf` and run your app with `sbt run` or if you are using custom config file, follow below procedure to load the file

**Using -Dconfig.resource**

This will search for an alternative configuration file in the application classpath (you usually provide these alternative configuration files into your application conf/ directory before packaging). Play will look into conf/ **so you don’t have to add conf/.**

```
$ /path/to/bin/<project-name> -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf
```

so try to run app with `sbt run -Dconfig.resource=my_conf.conf`

These two play documentation will hep you to get better idea
 https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ConfigFile 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ProductionConfiguration

Comment: Thanks, I renamed my config file to `/project/modules/my_module/conf/application.conf`, now when I run `sbt run` the configurations from that file are loaded. However, I also have a project config file at `/project/conf/application.conf`, which is included in the module configuration with `include "../../../conf/application.conf"`, but the configurations from the project file are not loaded. Any suggestions?

Comment: You will get better idea if you can go through the above docs

Comment: It seems likely the parent configuration file was not loading because it is located at `/project/conf/`, while I was executing `sbt run` from `project/modules/my_module`. However, the parent configuration file is still not loading when I run `sbt run my_module` from `/project` (I have also tried all likely values for the `include` path)